# Docker API push to private registry error

Tags: docker, api

I can't manage to push an image to a private registry using the docker API. I have read everything I found everywhere and tried everything with no luck...

I tried :

```html
curl -X POST -H "X-Registry-Auth:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" http://dockerapiurl:2375/images/registryurl/python/push?tag=6
```

OR

curl -X POST -H 'X-Registry-Auth:{"username": "xxxxxx","password": "xxxxx", "serveraddress": "xxxx.url.net", "auth": ""}' http://dockerapiurl:2375/images/registryurl/python/push?tag=6

I always get the same error :

{"errorDetail":{"message":"errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"},"error":"errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"}

If I use docker push in CLI mode everything works, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: i think X-Registry-Auth is deprecated

Comment: it seems to be used on the last API version : https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#section/Authentication or I got that wrong?

Comment: it needs to be encoded in base 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to be encoded in base 64, try this

```
XRA=`echo "{ \"username\": \"xxxxxx\", \"password\": \"xxxxxx\", \"email\": \"youmail@example.org\", \"serveraddress\": \"xxxxxx\" }" | base64 --wrap=0`
curl  -X POST  -d "" -H "X-Registry-Auth: $XRA" http://dockerapiurl:2375/images/registryurl/python/push?tag=6
```

end result should look like this

```
curl -X POST -d "" -H "X-Registry-Auth: eyAidXNlcm5hbWUiOiAieHh4eHh4IiwgInBhc3N3b3JkIjogInh4eHh4eCIsICJlbWFpbCI6ICJ5b3VtYWlsQGV4YW1wbGUub3JnIiB9Cg==" http://dockerapiurl:2375/images/registryurl/python/push?tag=6
```

Comment: I tried to encode it in base_64 before and still got the same error :{"errorDetail":{"message":"errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"},"error":"errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"}

Comment: Thanks I finally got it working, same code but with another registry. I'm not sure what's wrong with the one I used but I'll stop using it.

Comment: perhaps its not supporting this API version, you can try docker API v2